# Is it okay to pass false parameter to .skip() and .limit() if not used?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am creating an API with express and mongoose (MongoDB), though I am unsure if the following code is an alright practice?

```
module.exports.getUsers = (callback, opts) => {
    opts = {
        limit: opts.limit != undefined ? opts.limit : false,
        offset: opts.offset != undefined ? opts.offset : false
    }

    // User = mongoose model
    User.find({}).limit(opts.limit).offset(opts.offset).exec(callback);
}
```

I felt this (optional limit & offset) would simpler than having a chain of if-elses or having a completely new function for each.

Comment: seems okay. You will how ever get a SyntaxError because of a missing function keyword.

Comment: *"Does it have an ill effect if you pass `.limit(0).skip(0)`?"* No it does not. In fact to the query engine it's "implied" even if you don't explicitly pass it.

Comment: @Darkrum Forgot `=>`, fixed now.

Comment: @NeilLunn Alright, so it'd be better to pass 0 rather than false? I understand they will have the same effect but is it better to use 0?

Comment: Again it does not matter. `false` would be "interpreted" as `0`, but I think it's generally better practice to use `0` since that is the standard input. A simple "ternary" condition on your parameters should handle that.

Comment: Alright, I see what you mean now. I'll use 0.

Comment: @NeilLunn If you want, submit a summary of your comments above and I'll accept as an answer. Cheers for the help. (I'll delete this when you post answer)